# Get a class name on postgres heroku rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

For some reason I'm using MySQL locally, and have Postgres on my heroku app.

Locally I can do something like:

```
<%= @mybook.type %>
```

to produce "Book" (assuming @mybook is a record from the Book model).

In my heroku app, it seems as though .type isn't recognized though.. Any ideas for a substitution?

Comment: `type` is a reserved word in PostgreSQL, but I don't think it is in MySQL. You might consider a different name for that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@mybook.class` to get the class, `type` is the deprecated way of getting it.